# Filter one file based on pattern matching with the another file in Unix or R

Tags: r, linux, unix, grepl

If I have a file like this

```
1:10177[b38]A,AC
1:10235[b38]T,TA
1:10352[b38]T,TA
1:10505[b38]A,T
1:10506[b38]C,G
```

and another file like this

```
6:26762428[b38]C,
6:27333733[b38]T,
14:105766248[b38]A,
6:32465058[b38]C,
6:32465058[b38]C,
```

and I would like to filter the first file such that its beginning matches the second file. So for example if my first file looks like

```
1:10177[b38]A,AC
1:10235[b38]T,TA
1:10352[b38]T,TA
```

and my second file look like

```
1:10177[b38]A,
1:10234[b38]G,
```

then it should return `1:10177[b38]A,AC` because the first row from the first file matches the first row from the second row before comma.

I also tried doing this in R to obtain the boolean index after trimming the first so that only the text before the first comma is kept but it didn't work

```
second_file <- paste(second_file,collapse="|")
subset_of_first_file <- pbmclapply(first_file, function(x) grepl(x, second_file))
```

because it returns all false in a small example where there is a match.

Comment: Isn't this just an inner join? `merge` and `dplyr::inner_join` do that well.

Comment: Can you provide the inputs `first_file` and `second_file` in a reproducible format ?